# Get the official source code of the PHP ZipArchive class

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

How can I get the official source code for the PHP ZipArchive class?

Comment: Voting to reopen on the grounds that the question [seeks the canonical resource](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385479/584676).

Comment: Since this is on the cusp of being closed *again*, a reminder to [review the usage of the Seeking Recommendations close reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417480/584676); seeking the official/canonical resource is not a valid reason to use this close reason. The same question linked in my previous comment also backs up the FAQ post in this comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about the [PHP ZipArchive class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php): download the [PHP source code](http://www.php.net/downloads.php) and look for the appropriate file. You may be disappointed if you expect the source code to be PHP code because the source code is written in C Language.

Alternatively, PHP source code can also be found on [PHP Github Development Repository.](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/zip/php_zip.c)

You can also take a look at the [Examples](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/master/ext/zip/examples) folder for usage.